# "Мыть" и "помойка": понятия разные, корень один

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Помойка" — место, куда сваливают мусор, место явно грязное. "Мыть" — делать чистым. Но слова явно родственные. Почему так?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Помои - вода с отходами после мытья, то есть грязная вода, отсюда - помойка (суффикс К).